# Combining pro-drop with null morphemes

Tags: list-of-languages, inflection, pronouns

Some languages combine pro-drop with null or zero morphemes – inflectional morphemes, more particularly. Turkish is an example of this. To illustrate, the verb *istemek* = *to want* is inflected as follows (in present continuous):

1Sg: istiyor-um
2Sg: istiyor-sun
3Sg: istiyor__
1Pl: istiyor-uz
2Pl: istiyor-sunuz
3Pl: istiyor-lar

Note that in the 3rd person singular, there is no morpheme – or at least not one that’s phonetically realised. So, in that sense, we have a null morpheme. (*-yor-* is the morpheme for continuous, but there’s no morpheme for person.)
Next, Turkish is a pro-drop language. To say e.g. *I want to eat an apple*, one does not have to use the first-person pronoun *ben*, as in *Ben bir elma yemek istiyorum*, but can instead say: *Bir elma yemek istiyorum*. Similarly, in the third person one need not use the pronoun *o*. To say *He wants to eat an apple*, one need not say *O bir elma yemek istiyor*, but can say:

(T) *Bir elma yemek istiyor.*

Now, (T) is the kind of sentence I am interested in, as it contains *neither* a personal pronoun *nor* an inflectional suffix. (More carefully, neither is realised at the surface.)

My question simply is whether anyone can supply another language that exhibits this – ideally a language where this happens in the first person singular. It’s fine if the language is merely null-subject and not fully pro-drop (i.e. allowing pronoun dropping only for subjects). Of course, I don’t want a language like Japanese or Korean, which lacks inflection in the first place.

Comment: All I.E languages created independently a 3 person pronoun from a demonstrative, so before there was nothing as in your example. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_pronouns

Answer (score 2):

Technically, English (and Turkish) imperatives are pro-drop and feature the null morpheme.

But what is arguably really going on here is that the Turkish present-progressive endings are like a compound with copula, and Turkish has null copula for 3rd-person singular.  (The actual Turkish 3rd-person present tense is marked, eg etmek / eder.)

(This goes back to the etymology of -iyor.  If I recall correctly, it is a relatively recent innovation, and had some literal meaning, which is why it works like a noun or adjective, not a suffix - no vowel harmony.  And of course English present progressive also uses the copula.)

In that case, as we're counting a compound tense with the copula, then any pro-drop language with null copula and compound tenses would qualify.  For example, Russian (past tense).

Comment: This is very interesting: thank you! Although, is Russian past tense a good example? From what I understand, pronouns are harder to drop there – exactly because the verb is inflected only for number and gender. Also, you say that Turkish 3rd-person present tense is marked. You mean because the inf is *etmek*, but the 3rd-person present tense is *eder* and not just *et*? And it’s *istemek*, but *ister* and not just *iste*? Does that automatically mean it’s marked for **3rd** person, though? Couldn’t it be argued that it’s just marked as finite, or as finite and present tense?

Comment: In Russian one can definitely say «Пошел?». «Понравилось.» «Договорились.».  Is it sometimes ambiguous?  Yes.

Comment: Yes, if you want to argue there is a null after *-er* in *eder* you can, but then many more languages have some conjugation that fits your criteria.  Eg South Slavic present tense.  Or many Armenian tenses.

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/čekati#Conjugation (If in your analysis, you only count everything after *-a*.  And notice also *bi*.)

Comment: I like Serbo-Croatian as the third person really seems to be just stem-plus-nothing: čeka-0, and čeka-ti in the infinitive. I think it would be harder than in Turkish to say that it's marked for third person. You're right that there are plenty of example – Macedonian would be another; but they all have this in the 3rd person singular. Hence my question whether it also happens in another person, esp. 1st singular.

Comment: Actually, I think I just found one: Romanian. If the verb stem ends in a consonant, the first-person inflectional morpheme is null. Take *alerga* = *to run*. The stem is *alerg-* and the [inflection](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/alerga#Romanian) goes:  *alerg*, *alergi*, *aleargă*, *alergăm*, *alergați*, *aleargă*. Therefore, *I run* is just *Alerg*. I think that’s exactly the kind of example I was looking for.

Comment: To be precise, the Turkish suffix is -_yor_, or vowel plus -_yor_. Compare "korumak" ~ "koruyor" and "gelmek" ~ "geliyor".

Comment: Yes, Romanian, and also Armenian in some tenses.  Like եկա, all other forms are like 1st-person plus something else.  However... the whole premise of null morpheme is questionable, because there are stem changes (in Turkish too, eg *et-* becomes *ed-*).  So we should distinguish between surface form and lemma.  Like in English, 1st-person appears to take the lemma plus null morpheme, but then there is *am*.

Comment: @BillJ You're right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen literature that advances the thesis that languages without "pro-drop" tend to have verb that inflect to distinguish some, but not all person/number categories (I think the typical examples used to illustrate this claim are English, French and German), while languages with "pro-drop" tend to either have inflected verbs that (mostly) distinguish between all the person/number categories, or verbs that do not inflect. This generalization is mentioned in the Wikipedia article on "[Pro-drop languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language#Generalizations_across_languages)".

This would imply that in a language with "pro-drop", a null affix would most likely only mark one person/number category, not several.

Based on what I've read, marking the third person with a null affix on the verb is not uncommon, although I don't have any numbers to give you. I haven't heard of this being a common strategy for marking the first person singular, although it probably exists in some pro-drop language.

[Navajo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo_grammar#Pronominal_inflection) is an example of a language with prefixes to mark subjects and objects where a third-person subject (singular or plural) is marked with a "null" affix.